# Creating a correlation loop to print and save png for 30 different data sets

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I'm new to stackoverflow but have found the community amazingly helpful in all my previous questions. However, I couldn't quite find an answer to this question so here I am.

My question has to deal with multiple data sets that I have and if there is a way to loop all the data sets through a loop of correlations that print and save the pngs. This is using fantasy basketball statistics and I'm just running pairwise correlations to try to see if there are positive or negative relationships between two player's points.

[Here is a link to a Google Sheet with an example of some of my data.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aQDfCgToDArkRoVfYuHgw0J8zqiLX0uVGBjcawhXiV4/edit?usp=sharing)

This is just a brief example of the data I'm working with and it's organized by date least recent to most recent going downwards (not really important). The name of this dataframe is "bucks". My real data has about 10-20 total player columns in it for every NBA team, which is 30 teams.

**Question 1**: I assume this part is easier and can be done. Can I loop a correlation for all my players to be correlation against each other and for this to print a plot and save it as a png somewhere on my computer or dropbox? (e.g., Brandon Knight vs. Antetokounmpo, Middleton, Mayo then Antetokounmpo vs. Middleton, Mayo, etc.) I have previously run a corrplot for each team to make this simpler and only have to print out one plot so that is an option for me as well.

**Question 2**: Can I then take this correlation loop and apply it to the other 29 teams in the NBA that I have data for? How would I go about doing this? Because these are all located in different dataframes, is this possible do tell a loop to go into different dataframes and not stay within the same one?

Here's some example code of my process so far. It's been very simplistic and I've used a new line copy/pasted for each different team.

```
library(corrplot)

#Data Import from Google Drive--------------
hawks = read.csv(file = "<insert my Google Drive link here>")
hawks[hawks == 0] <- NA
spurs = read.csv(file = "<insert my Google Drive link here>")
spurs[spurs == 0] <- NA
...
wizards = read.csv(file = "<insert my Google Drive link here>")
wizards[wizards == 0] <- NA

#Team by Team Correlations----------------------------------
CORhawks = cor(hawks[c(2:10)], use="pairwise.complete.obs")
CORspurs = cor(spurs[c(2:10)], use="pairwise.complete.obs")
...
CORwizards = cor(wizards[c(2:10)], use="pairwise.complete.obs")

#Team by Team Color Set up-----------------------------------
colhawks <- colorRampPalette(c("midnightblue", "brown2" ))
colnets <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "gray80" ))
...
colwizards <- colorRampPalette(c("firebrick2", "gray80"))

#Team by Team Bubble Plotting--------------------------------------------
corrplot(CORhawks, order ="hclust", tl.col="black", col = colhawks(2), outline=TRUE)
corrplot(CORspurs, order ="hclust",  tl.col="black", col = colspurs(2), outline=TRUE)
...
corrplot(CORwizards, order ="hclust",  tl.col="black", col = colwizards(2), outline=TRUE)
```

Technically, this system will get the job done for me. I'm just wondering how best to write a loop to expedite this process and help me understand loop writing so I can do it in the future.

Thanks for any and all help and let me know if you need anything clarified!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just working on something like this yesterday for a scientist's data.

Put all of the common parts of your computation into a function. Put all of the variable stuff (filenames, etc) in a list (or create a list from reading from a file). Then loop over your list, running your function on each item.

Here's some example code:

```
TEAMS <- list( list(name="Hawks",
                    file="<insert Google Drive link here>",
                    colors=colorRampPalette(c("midnightblue", "brown2"))
               ),
               list(name="Nets",
                    file="<insert Google Drive link here>",
                    colors=colorRampPalette(c("black", "gray80")),
               )
         )

plot_team <- function (x) {

    # Read in the data and clean it up
    team            <- read.csv(file = x$file)
    team[team == 0] <- NA

    # Calculate the correlation
    CORteam <- cor(team[c(2:10)], use="pairwise.complete.obs")

    # Create unique output filename
    output_filename <- paste0(x$name,".png")

    # Open the file for the plot to be written to
    png(output_filename)

    # Draw the plot
    corrplot(CORteam, order ="hclust", tl.col="black", col = x$colors(2), outline=TRUE)

    # Close the file
    dev.off()
}

for (team in TEAMS) {
    plot_team(team)
}
```